# Storing HashMap Object in Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

Tags: java, android, hashmap, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am trying to upload a HashMap to GCS.  The first thing I am doing is saving my HashMap to internal memory:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> picViews = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();   
//Write the local file with total picture views
private void writeViewFile(String filename) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        s.writeObject(picViews);
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using the following code I am trying to create am object named "myViewsTest" in my bucket "isthiscute-rankings":

```
    public void uploadViews() throws Exception {
    // Authorization.
    if (googleCredential == null) {
        googleCredential = authorize();
    }

    // Set up global Storage instance.
    client = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, googleCredential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    String fileName = "myViews";

    StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
    object.setBucket(BUCKET_NAME_RANKINGS);

    //Read stored HashMap as an ObjectInputStream
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> testHash;
    try {
        //This correctly reads the HashMap from file
        testHash = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) ois.readObject();

        String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(ois);
        InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType, ois);

        //This does not add a HashMap object to my Storage Object
        Storage.Objects.Insert insert = client.objects().insert(BUCKET_NAME_RANKINGS, object, content);
        insert.setName("myViewsTest");

        //This does add a HashMap to my Storage Object --> Fails to upload
        insert.set("object", testHash);

        insert.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fis.close();
        ois.close();
    }

}
```

Finally I try to download the object.  This is what I am attempting:

```
public void downloadViews() throws Exception {
    // Authorization.
    if (googleCredential == null) {
        googleCredential = authorize();
    }

    // Set up global Storage instance.
    client = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, googleCredential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    String fileName = "myViewsTest";

    String destinationDirectory = this.getCacheDir().toString();
    File file = new File(destinationDirectory + "/" + fileName);

    Storage.Objects.Get get = client.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME_RANKINGS, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> testHash = null;
    try {
        get.executeAndDownloadTo(oos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fos.close();
        oos.close();
    }

}
```

I am unsure as to how to input the raw data from the ObjectOutputStream back to my original HashMap "testHash".  From what I am able to see in my GCS bucket I do not believe the correct data is even being saved to my bucket.  It is 0 bytes and when I download the object and view in Notepad++ it is not readable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Jenny

UPDATE:
The suggestion from Brandon Yarbrough allows me to read the internal file I created for my HashMap ("myViews").  My new problem occurs when trying to upload the HashMap object to my GCS bucket.  From what I can tell the InputStream containing my HashMap ("ois") is not being attached to my Storage Object.

Answer (score 1):

You're using ObjectOutputStream to turn a Serializable Java Object, a HashMap in this case, into streaming data. Reconstituting that stream of data into an object is called "deserializing." In this case, the corresponding stream is an `ObjectInputStream`. You might use it like so:

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

  HashMap<Integer, Integer> testHash;
  testHash = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) ois.readObject();

  ois.close();
```

For this example, I've left a file as part of the operation, but keep in mind that there's no need to do so. You could almost as easily stream your download directly into the ObjectInputStream.

You may also want to consult the documentation on [ObjectInputStreams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream()).